# Elegant way to test for absolute differences via testthat::expect_equal()

Tags: r, testthat

I am currently implementing unit tests with `testthat::expect_equal()`. For `testthat` version 3, this tests for relative differences unless the difference between the input values is very small, in which case, the test is based on an absolute difference measure. Is there an elegant way to force `expect_equal` to use an absolute distance measure, even when the differences between $x$ and $y$ are not small?

Here is a [link](https://testthat.r-lib.org/reference/equality-expectations.html) to the documentation of `expect_equal`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to test for absolute difference is of course via `expect_true()` - e.g. assume that `X = 1`, `Y = 1.05` and the absolute difference is allowed to be `0.1`.

Then one can write

```
library(testthat)

X <- 1
Y <- 1.05
tolerance <- 0.1
expect_true(abs(X - Y) < tolerance)
```